# What's special about tablets with "FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL" set?

Tags: android, android-notifications

The API of [FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL) says something special about tablets:

> Bit to be bitwise-ored into the flags field that should be set if the
>   notification should be canceled when it is clicked by the user. On
>   tablets, the

What is the special sentence about tablets?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an incomplete sentence was checked in. Git blame reveals [this commit](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/2561b0b10a55841a08e0e1d467e73e10b1bf256d) which also has some changes done to TabletStatusBar.java. Not sure what's the connection, though.

Comment: so what is the full info? what was missing?

Comment: Actually, it was introduced in [this earlier commit](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/cb109a0e). I honestly don't remember what we were planning to put there; even in Honeycomb when we first introduced the ability to clear individual notifications, FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL was not affected.

Comment: I think it's kind of hilarious that no one knows what the rest of the sentence is supposed to say, and that multiple people have been confused by it. I bet someone just put it in the first half of what looks like an important condition as a prank and there isn't actually anything special that happens on tablets.

Comment: Yeah, there really is nothing special. (You can confirm this in the source code to the NotificationManagerService and SystemUI.)

Just imagine it says: "On tablets, the behavior is exactly the same as on phones."